# how to set the line space for list?

Tags: itext7

so just look at the iText Jump-Start Tutorial of [Chapter 1: Introducing basic building blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-1-introducing-basic-building-blocks) Figure 1.2: List example, how to set the line space for the generated lists?

Comment: Just like answers in stack overflow are expected to help without the need to follow external links, questions should not require one to look off-site either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line spacing is controlled by LEADING property in iText7.

One of the ways to specify leading would be to use `setFixedLeading` or `setMultipliedLeading` on iText7's `Paragraph` class and then add those `Paragraph` instances directly to `ListItem` instances.

A helper method for creating such a list item based on a text string looks as follows:

```
private ListItem createListItemWithLeading(String text) {
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(text);
    paragraph.setFixedLeading(30);
    paragraph.setMargin(0);
    ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
    listItem.add(paragraph);
    return listItem;
}
```

Another way, as there is currently no `setFixedLeading` or `setMultpliedLeading` setters on other elements than Paragraphs, would be to set this property manually to the list:

```
list.setProperty(Property.LEADING, new Leading(Leading.MULTIPLIED, 2.5f));
// Add the list
document.add(list);
```

Please be careful when use `setProperty` directly and do it at your own risk. The preferred way is still to use getters/setters provided in the public API.

Comment: thanks. Can you give some detailed sample code for the 1st method: add those Paragraph nstances directly to ListItem Instances. I've also tried the 2nd way with setProperty, I have tried with 0f and 20f to replace the 2.5f, but it seems the line space was not changed at all.

Comment: 20 seems like a huge multiplier. 0 does not make a lot of sense. If you are looking for fixed leading, you can go with `new Leading(Leading.FIXED, 15f))`

Comment: @cao if the answer works for you (and no other answer is better) you should accept the answer (click the tick at its upper left).